# MAMP Localhost wordpress is not reading MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost, mamp

I am not very computer savvy.

I am trying to setup a localhost for my live wordpress website. I installed MAMP free on Mac 10.11.6 El Capitan. Themes and plugins load fine on localhost but it is not reading my database, so pages are not loading.

I did these:

1. Created database and imported my live website database through MAMP PHPAdmin. Database shows up fine.
2. Downloaded and setup wordpress. Theme and plugins work.
3. Set user permissions to Check ALL.
4. Updated permalinks.
5. Went to wp_options in database and replaced with my local wordpress name for site url and home:

The server for Apache and MySQL lights up green. Am using port 80 and 3360.
What else do I need to do to get the database and wordpress connected?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot where you are stuck? You can do this by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported the SQL from your live site into your local database you will have to take other steps... the database at the moment may well be redirecting to your live site URL and so it looks as though it's working when it isn't.

Once you have copied all the files from your live site to your MAMP install under the htdocs folder, and imported the live database to your local MAMP MySQL configuration, then you will need to do these things (assuming there's not any other complications such as using Wordfence, or being an https:// site ):

1. Edit the wp-config.php file to set DB_HOST to 'localhost' (if it's not already set to localhost) and update the DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD and DB_USER to those for your MAMP test database.
2. Use the package from interconnect to replace the live URLs in the MAMP database to the correct local URL https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/  - please be SURE that you are pointing at your new MAMP based database and not the current live site when you go to whatever-your-mamp-site-is-called.com/replace

Information on migration following the 'official' WordPress approach can be found here https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Please also check that your live site is still working as I am a little concerned you might have updated the site URL to the test one in error. I hope you haven't but it is worth checking... !